# Onenote not as convenient as Google Keep. Solutions to integrate?

Tags: sync, microsoft-onenote, onedrive

I am a heavy onenote user on the PC, but I find there is a 1-3 second delay on my phone between tapping new note and actually being able to type. As I use notes on my phone primarily for quickly capturing information and reliably finding it later, this delay is too long. Google Keep does this far better, but I hate to have my notes in two places.

I would be very happy to be able to find a way to add simple (plain text files would be ok but not perfect) notes very quickly and have them somehow synced to the unfiled notes section of my OneNote, which is on Skydrive.

Comment: To date, there's no way to export/import from/to Google Keep, so I don't think there's going to be a solution for you. Perhaps someone has an alternative to the OneNote app.